# Unable to parse JSON returned by server

Tags: android, json, sencha-touch-2

I see error:  "Unable to parse JSON returned by server" when I use my Sencha Touch 2 on my android 2.3.5. When I run this app from desktop (Chrome browser) - it works fine.

My Json is valid:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "result": [
    {
      "key": "music",
      "count": 3
    },
    {
      "key": "cinema",
      "count": 13
    },
    {
      "key": "theatre",
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "nightlife",
      "count": 0
    },
    {
      "key": "exhibition",
      "count": 14
    },
    {
      "key": "restaurant",
      "count": 0
    },
    {
      "key": "sport",
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "social",
      "count": 2
    },
    {
      "key": "conference",
      "count": 4
    },
    {
      "key": "festival",
      "count": 0
    },
    {
      "key": "other",
      "count": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT:
I load date using store:

```
store.load({
       callback: function (records, operation, success){
        console.log('loaded');
      },
      scope: this
    });
```

Store config:

```
Ext.define('EIA.store.Categories', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
config: {
  model: 'EIA.model.Category',
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'URL',
    reader: {
      type: 'json',
      rootProperty: 'result'
     }
   }
 }
});
```

Comment: I guess you're using a store. Could you add its code to your post. Or any other code your think is relevant.

Comment: try to read the json as a textfile from your assets folder etc.

Comment: Does this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739520/sencha-touch-2-android-json-reader?rq=1

Comment: this solution works for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236056/when-loading-a-store-in-sencha-touch-2-how-can-i-stop-the-additional-options-ht